# How to make Koen Claessen's concurrency monad with pure variables?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, monads, continuation-passing

It's known how to make a pure concurrency monad based on [`ContT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#t:ContT), based on a functional pearl of Koen Claessen:

```hs
data Action m where
  Atom :: m (Action m) -> Action m
  Fork :: [Action m] -> Action m
  Stop :: Action m

fork :: Applicative m => [ContT (Action m) m a] -> ContT (Action m) m ()
fork processes = ContT $ \next -> Fork <$> sequenceA (next () : [ process $ const $ pure $ Const | ContT process <- processes ])
```

How would I implement shared variables like `IORef`s or `MVar`s? Or at least an async/await mechanism?
Bonus points if it's polymorphic in the type of data passed.

Comment: Depending on what kind of pure you need, would it suffice to use [`ST`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html) as the base monad?  Then you could at least eliminate into a pure value without relying on the dark arts.

Comment: @luqui I want to keep the base monad parametric, but maybe there are some basic constraints on the base monad that one could make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume by “implement shared variables like `IORefs` or `MVars`” you mean in a way *other* than just having the underlying monad `m` include `IO` and using `IORef`/`MVar`. That’s straightforward, something like this:

```
newVar :: a -> ContT (Action IO) IO (IORef a)
newVar x = ContT $ \ k -> Atom $ do
  v <- newIORef x
  pure $ k v
```

A conventional way to add mutable variables to the “poor man’s concurrency monad” *purely* is by adding additional actions to the `Action` type for creating, reading, and writing mutable variables. Suppose we have some type `Var m a` that identifies mutable variables of type `a` that can be created & accessed in `m`.

```
data Action m where
  Atom :: m (Action m) -> Action m
  Fork :: [Action m] -> Action m
  Stop :: Action m

  New   :: (Var m a -> Action m) -> Action m
  Read  :: Var m a -> (a -> Action m) -> Action m
  Write :: Var m a -> a -> Action m -> Action m
```

Notice that the type parameter `a` does not appear in the result type of these new constructors, so it’s existentially quantified, and variables may thus contain values of any type. `New` is an action that continues to another action with a fresh variable as an argument; `Read`, given a variable, continues to the next action with that variable’s value; and `Write`, given a variable and a new value, writes the value into the variable before continuing.

Like `fork`, these would be constructed with helper functions that produce actions in `ContT (Action m) m`:

```
newVar
  :: (Applicative m)
  => ContT (Action m) m (Var m a)
newVar = ContT $ \ k -> pure (New (Atom . k))

readVar
  :: (Applicative m)
  => Var m a -> ContT (Action m) m a
readVar v = ContT $ \ k -> pure (Read v (Atom . k))

writeVar
  :: (Applicative m)
  => Var m a -> a -> ContT (Action m) m ()
writeVar v x = ContT $ \ k -> pure (Write v x (Atom (k ())))
```

After that, you just have to decide on a suitable representation of `Var`. One method is a data family, which makes it relatively easy to use `IORef`/`MVar` when `IO` is available, and something else like an `Int` index into an `IntMap` otherwise.

```
data family Var (m :: Type -> Type) (a :: Type) :: Type

data instance Var IO a = IOVar { unIOVar :: !(MVar a) }
```

Of course this is just a sketch; a much more fleshed out implementation can be found in the [`monad-par`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-par-0.3.5/docs/Control-Monad-Par.html) package, whose design is described in [A Monad for Deterministic Parallelism](https://simonmar.github.io/bib/papers/monad-par.pdf) (Marlow, Newton, & Peyton Jones 2011); its `Par` monad is basically a continuation monad around an action type like this, and its `IVar` abstraction is implemented similarly to this, with some additional constraints like extra strictness to enforce determinism and allow pure execution of internally impure code (an `IVar` secretly wraps an `IORef`).

Comment: "something else like an `Int` index into an `IntMap` otherwise."

That map must then reside in a state in `m`, I'm assuming?

Comment: Some of your constructions are missing `fmap` or `return` in order to lift the inner computations in `ContT` into `m`, I believe.

Comment: I would have expected an async/await pattern giving rise to `async :: ContT (Action m) m a -> ContT (Action m) m (Var a)` and `await :: Var a -> ContT (Action m) m a` to be easier to implement directly in the `Action m` type than variables, but I can't figure out. In case you have a quick idea, I'd be very interested :) otherwise I might open a follow-up question.

Comment: @Turion: Thanks, I think I’ve fixed those mistakes. That’s what happens when you don’t test the code! Yes, the hypothetical `IntMap` (or [`DMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-map-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Dependent-Map.html#t:DMap)) solution would need to go in the state of `m` somewhere. Effectively, an `IORef` *is* stored in the state of `IO`, but of course that’s just the Haskell runtime itself. I’m not sure about `async`/`await`, will think on it. `monad-par` uses `IVar` for that: `spawn` forks a task and returns an `IVar`, and using `get` on that `IVar` awaits the task’s result.